# Ubuntu 19 does not show the wired configuration option

Tags: networking, 19.04, wired

My Ubuntu 19 LTS does not show me the wired configuration option(need to fix this on this Ubuntu version - was working on 16 LTS), only my Wifi works. 
I did this (After that, I gave reboot several times):

```
$ sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms echo "blacklist r8169" | sudo tee -a \
      /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

#### My current network configuration screen:

[image: my current network config screen].

#### My current configs:

```
$ ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1145  bytes 106916 (106.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1145  bytes 106916 (106.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.115  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::cda3:45ed:a42:83e8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 28:56:5a:e9:b5:05  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 12335  bytes 14044457 (14.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5561  bytes 1311885 (1.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces:
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0

iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

```
$ sudo lshw -c network:
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 32
       serial: 28:56:5a:e9:b5:05
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.0.0-16-generic firmware=RM.4.4.1.c2-00057-QCARMSWP-1 ip=192.168.0.115 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:125 memory:d5000000-d51fffff
```